# Is this function really tail-recursive?

Tags: c++, c, tail-recursion

I read about recursion in *Programming Interviews Exposed* (3rd ed.) where they present the following recursive `factorial` function:

```
int factorial(int n){
    if (n > 1) { /* Recursive case */
        return factorial(n-1) * n;
    } else {     /* Base case */
        return 1;
    }
}
```

On the bottom of the same page (page 108) they talk about tail-recursive functions:

> Note that when the value returned by the recursive call is itself immediately returned, as in the preceding definition for `factorial`, the function is *tail-recursive*.

But is this really the case here? The last call in the function is the `*` call, so won't this stack frame be preserved (if we don't take compiler optimization into account)? Is this really tail-recursive?

Comment: This function is indeed _not_ tail-recursive.

Comment: The naive recursive implementation of factorial is the classic example of a recursive function that is not tail-recursive, often used to illustrate how to obtain tail-recursion by use of an accumulator  ... I suggest that you get yourself a different book.

Comment: You write "so won't this stack frame be preserved (if we don't take compiler optimization into account)" -- but compiler optimization is irrelevant for *this* function, because the stack frame *cannot* be eliminated ... precisely because the function *isn't* tail-recursive. A function that *is* tail-recursive, so the stack frame *can* be eliminated by an optimizing compiler, is given by Eric Jablow. The optimization isn't all that important for C C++, but is essential for functional language like F# and Haskell, where loops are normally implemented recursively.

Comment: @JimBalter: So I take it that no compiler would optimize it to use an accumulator and thus make it tail-recursive? (Actually, that *does* sound a bit overreaching, now that I think about it…)

Comment: I doubt it, as such a rewrite can be arbitrarily complex, depending on the function.

Comment: @beta Interestingly, GCC has been [able to optimize](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22PTAEBUE8AcFNUgewK4CdQGNEBN4AtZVYAaURdAG0QENtRqA7UWAD2oFtoLYA6AKACWDAC6gAZtQzCAFENENk7AJSgA3n1CgBY0NIXtQAXkOgADEo2bQRYWiYBGANyWbd0PtAAqcZJkeAtKD2Ss4AvnxAAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%22%7D%5D%7D) the non-tail-recursive factorial for some years now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not tail-recursive.  The result being returned by `factorial(n-1)` still has to be multiplied by `n`, which requires that `factorial(n)` regain control (thus mandating that the call to `factorial(n-1)` be a call rather than a jump).

With that said, even if it were tail-recursive, the compiler still might not do TCO on it.  Depends on the compiler and the optimizations that you ask it to do.

Comment: At least the book is correct when it says "*Some* compilers can perform tail call elimination ...".

Comment: Right. So the book is simply wrong when stating that this function is tail-recursive. Thanks!

Comment: The book is also misleading when it says that all recursive functions can be written iteratively. It's technically true, since you can always emulate recursion with a stack, but that isn't really an iterative form of the same function. Many recursive functions do not have straightforward iterative counterparts.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite it to be tail-recursive:

```
int factorial(int n){
    return factorial2(n, 1);
}
int factorial2(int n, int accum) {
    if (n < 1) {
       return accum;
    } else {
        return factorial2(n - 1, accum * n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from this link: [tail recursion using factorial as example](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion)

```
 factorial(n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
 }//equivalent to your code

 This definition is NOT tail-recursive since the recursive call to 
 factorial is not the last thing in the function 
 (its result has to be multiplied by n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tail Recursive` is a special case of recursion in which the last operation of the function is a recursive call. In a tail recursive function, there are no pending operations to be performed on return from a recursive call.
The function you mentioned is not a tail recursive because there is a pending operation i.e multiplication to be performed on the return from a recursive call.
In case you did this:

```
    int factorial(int n,int result)
    {
        if (n > 1)
        { /* Recursive case */
             return factorial(n-1,n*result);
        }
        else
        {     /* Base case */
            return result;
        }
    }
```

would be a tail recursive function. since it has no pending operation on return from a recursive call.